# Force copy (then destroy) on move-only type

Tags: c++, move-semantics, shallow-copy

Consider the following function of a lock-free work-stealing (de)que:

```
template<class T>
inline T WorkStealQ<T>::Steal(void)
{
    auto tail{_tail.load(std::memory_order_acquire)};
    if (_head.load(std::memory_order_acquire) <= tail) return T();
    auto task{_tasks[tail & _mask]};
    if (_tail.compare_exchange_weak(tail, tail + 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed)) return task;
    return T();
}
```

But what if `T` is only moveable but non-copyable? The issue is that the reading of the item from the buffer is a copy operation, and cannot be changed to `auto task{std::move(_tasks[tail & _mask])};` because another concurrent operation could also move it, in which case any move constructor which is not read-only but also modifies the original (such as nulling some pointer to a resource) would break the algorithm.

Note that the overall semantics of `Steal()` do perform only a move from an external point of view, since only one concurrent operation will return with the `T` that was stored at that location; any others who lose the race would fail the `compare_exchange_weak()`. Thus, the operation doesn't break the semantics of a moveable only `T` as far as the user is concerned. Unfortunately, internally it needs to make a temporary shallow copy of `T` until it determines whether to complete it as a move or give up, leaving it in the buffer (it's basically a two-phase move with a check occurring in the middle).

One way to do this would be make copy constructor and copy assignment private members of `T` and have a `friend WorkStealQ`. The problem is what to do in the case of third-party library classes I may want to use as `T`. Is there any other option in that case than just using pointers to such objects rather than storing them intrusively (and thus getting a performance hit)? I'm assuming `memcpy` won't work even for a shallow copy in the case of classes with virtual functions.

Comment: It is times like this that I think of dear old tony's advice; the first rule of lock free programming?  Don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be to have a separate shallow_copy class that is defined explicitly for each T, and use that in your work-stealing function.  That will also allow you to deal with whatever issues cause your type to be move-only (as you can't know a priori that a temporary copy will avoid those issues).

Comment: Do you mean shallow_copy<T> derived from T? This would work if T's members are protected rather than private. I'd have to specialize WorkStealQ functions on shallow_copy<T> vs just T since using shallow_copy on something like an integer or pointer would be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Deriving from T might not be such a good idea if it won't have everything that T does.  If T's members are protected or private, and it is not copyable, then it seems to me that basically means that there's no telling what is happening on the move, and the concept of a two-part move may very well break the internals of the class, for all you know.  It may be that I'm misunderstanding something about the algorithm, though.